# Excel not Closing in vba access module

Tags: vba, ms-access

What's wrong on the function below. Excel.exe*32 not closing in task manager.

```
Function formatExcel()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = "C:\This file\queryCentering.xlsx"
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"        

        Columns("C:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Rows("2:2").Select 
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select  
        Selection.RowHeight = 15 

    End With
    wb.Save
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What are you doing with `Selection.RowHeight = 15`? Seems like the end result is to select some cells but what happens with that?

Answer (score 1):

You have `With wb.Sheets(1)`, but don't actually use it.

Also, it is advisable to not use the Selection object.

Try this (note the `.` before `Columns`)

```
With wb.Sheets(1)
    .Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"        
    .Columns("C:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Comment: Thanks- how do I translate this below into .row Rows("2:2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.RowHeight = 15

Comment: @pinkrose: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add it there - but it seems like a new question, so perhaps post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

YOU HAVE TO CLOSE EVERY SINGLE OBJECT THAT YOU OPEN.  Andre underscored the issue.  Look very closely at your code.